# Proper reactive operator for two methods

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two methods dependent on each other.

```
Flux<DataBuffer> flux = service1.get();
Mono<String> s = service2.store(flux);
```

`service1.get()` returns `Flux<DataBuffer>` or `Flux.error` in case unsuccessful get operation.

`service2.store(Flux<DataBuffer> flux)` return `Mono<String>` or `Mono.error` in case unsuccessful store operation.

Service2 is reactive feign client, it stores data to file and returns reference.

I need to make service2 calling dependent on service1, but I want to preserve the param Flux and call each method just once.
The aim is to call `service2.store` just in case successful response from `service1.get`.

E.g.

```
public Mono<String> mainMethod() {
    return service1.get()
      .unknownOperator(flux -> service2.store(flux))
      .doOnError(e -> log.error(e.getMessage));
}
```

Can you advise me the right operator instead of `unknownOperator`.

Error should be handled such way:

1. error in `service1.get` should be logged and returned from mainMethod. `service2.store` cannot be called.
2. error in `service2.store` should be logged and returned from mainMethod.

Comment: Your question is unclear, you talk about `service1.get` And `service2.store` but later in your last example you are calling `service1.get` and `service.get(flux)` instead. Please update your question to have a correct code example including all return types from the functions. Do they return `error` or do they return `empty` and if different parts go wrong how do you wish the errors to be handled.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the example, and added details about error handling. It should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it also strange to have Flux as a parameter in service2.store? I'm guessing that you just want to do `service1.get().collectList()` so you have a Mono of the result of service1.
Afterwards you could just do a flatmap? e.g.

```
service1.get()
    .collectList()
    .flatmap(service2::store) // .flatmap(list -> service2.store(list)
    .doOnError(e -> log.error(e.getMessage))
```

Comment: Problem with passing a list is that you need to store the entire list in memory which could lead to OOM errors on large files. Better to stream each bytebuffer then

Comment: Makes sense, but should he then have `DataBuffer` as param instead of `Flux<DataBuffer>`? I see a lot of beginning ppl passing Mono of Flux as param to methods, but if you set up your pipe/stream correctly or adjust your code accordingly, this should not (?) be needed.
There could be cases where you pass Flux or Mono as param, but haven't encountered them yet so I could be wrong on that part

Comment: passing a producer is not inherently wrong, as long as you make sure that the chain is intact, so that reactor can assemble

Comment: @Toerktumlare can you specify how to achieve that?